# Unknown class <MDToolbar>

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I got this error

```
> kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <MDToolbar>
```

build.spec

```
> requirements =
> python3,kivy==2.0.0,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip,pillow
```

Edit: MDToolbar moved to MDTopAppBar and BottomAppBar

Answer (score 0):

Add KivyMD to requirements.
kivymd==1.0.2 is the latest version for now, change it if you use another version

```
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd==1.0.2,pillow
```